# Refactoring navBar jQuery code

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I already have my navBar working properly, but I have a lot of `if` statements in my code... essentially 1 `if` per navBar option. What I am hoping for is if you guys could help me out a little bit to make all of those if statements one simple command. I know it can be done, but having some trouble with it...

My main reason for doing this is because if I want to add items to my navBar I don't have to go back into the jQuery code to add more `if` statements.

If you don't care to read all of the code here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jqNVC/1/)

**HTML Layout**

Some options in the navbar don't have sub menu's others do.

```
<ul id="posiNav">
   <li>
       <a href="#">Home</a>
   <li>
   <li>
       <a href="#">Overview</a>
   <li>
   <li>
       <a class="dropable"><img class="arrow" id="option1Arrow" src=".."/>Option 1</a>
       <ul class="navDrop" id="option1Drop">
            <li><a href="#">sub-menu</a></li>
       </ul>
   <li>
   <li>
       <a class="dropable"><img class="arrow" id="option2Arrow" src=".."/>Option 2</a>
       <ul class="navDrop" id="option2Drop">
            <li><a href="#">sub-menu</a></li>
       </ul>
   <li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.dropable').click(function () {
    //The first part of this code doesn't need to be changed, it's strictly to rotate the arrow
    var child = $(this).children();
    var id = child.attr("id");
    var currAngle = child.getRotateAngle();

    if(currAngle == -180){
        child.rotate({
            duration:500,
            angle:-180,
            animateTo:0
        });
    }
    else{
        child.rotate({
            duration: 500,
            angle:0,
            animateTo:-180
        });
    }

    //This is what I would like to abridge
    if (id == 'option1Arrow') {
        $('#option1Drop').slideToggle("slow");
    }
    if (id == 'option2Arrow') {
        $('#option2Drop').slideToggle("slow");
    }
});
```

I also have jQuery code that checks what page you are on, and if it is that page it drops the sub menu down if there is one...

```
$(function() {
    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('option1') > -1 ) {
        $('#option1Drop').slideToggle("slow");
        $('#option1Arrow').rotate({
            duration: 500,
            angle: 0,
            animateTo:-180
        });
    }
    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('option2') > -1 ) {
        $('#option2Drop').slideToggle("slow");
        $('#option2Arrow').rotate({
            duration: 500,
            angle: 0,
            animateTo:-180
        });
    }
});
```

**CSS**
-- Not really important with regards to the refractoring, but for the sake of completeness and neatness for you guys here it is:

```
#posiNav {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: rgb(179, 35, 23);
    color: white;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px 0px
}

#posiNav a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 3px 0px;
    color: inherit;
}

#posiNav li {
    padding: 3px 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: rgb(204,204,204);
}

#posiNav li:hover {
    background-color: gray;
}

.navDrop {
    background: rgb(221, 220, 220);
    border-style: none;
    color: black;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.arrow {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Use `.class` instead of `#ID`. You arrows direction logic makes no sense. (...The design is really for a client?)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan You have to elaborate more on what you mean... the fact that you can only click on the arrow? or the way they are facing? To answer the first question it is behaving differently in the fiddle than it is on the live site.

Comment: For example why you use `#option1Drop, #option2Drop  {
    display:none;
}` ? isn't it easier to remove all those ID ans set `display:none;` to your `.navDrop` ?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I already use the class for something. I need the ID to be unique. That is also the purpose of my question...Refactoring, so that if I have 100 dropdowns with different IDs I don't need 100 if statements. --About the `.navDrop` thanks for pointing that out. I missed that.

Comment: Why you need all those ID? Just being curious.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan the IDs are more for when I am on the specific page.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks for the help Roko... I can't always make the catch my own mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this can help you:

Decalre a variable which holds the id of the target ul which is getting slide.

```
var tgt = $(this).siblings('ul')[0].id;
```

then you can do this

```
if(currAngle == -180){
    child.rotate({
        duration:500,
        angle:-180,
        animateTo:0
    });
    $('#'+tgt).slideToggle("slow");  //<-----here
}else{
    child.rotate({
        duration: 500,
        angle:0,
        animateTo:-180
    });
    $('#'+tgt).slideToggle("slow"); //<---and here
}
```

[**Fiddle to try**](http://jsfiddle.net/jqNVC/2/)

#### Another way as seen in the comments`:

As you already have a classname for the `<ul>` which is sliding out then you can change to this to work with less worries:

add this variable:

```
 var tgt = $(this).siblings('ul');
```

and add this :

```
tgt.slideToggle("slow");
```

[**Another fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jqNVC/3/)

Comment: That is great and works well. Can you just explain the `[0]` in the `tgt` decleration

Comment: its the index of the target `ul`. although you can use this; `$(this).siblings('ul').attr("id");`

Comment: So if I had another `ul` in the `li` I could use `[1]` to get to it?

Comment: The second method that you came up with... that circumvents the `id` right? so `tgt` is that whole `ul` object correct?

Comment: yes correct you can omit the ids from there, so that you can then just put your uls there without changing any id, i mean this is less maintainable (_in terms of checking and updating the ids_).